# Azure Mobile App Authorization issue

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I am running into an issue with authorization with a new Mobile App service.

I have an old Mobile Service (the predecessor to Mobile Apps), and it works fine with the exact same code. We created a new Mobile Apps service for a new environment, and now it seems to require authorization.

I do not have any `[Authorize]` attributes in the .Net backend. I don't want any authorization to occur with the API calls.

I believe I have the service setup correctly to disable authorization/authentication.
[image: Azure portal]

So I'm stuck trying to figure out why I'm getting this response in Postman...

```
{
   "message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
```

I believe I have the correct headers that need to be sent with the request from Postman..

[image: Headers]

When I try calling the API from my Xamarin Forms app, I get a similar exception,

`The request could not be completed.  (Unauthorized)`

Comment: Try to add a `x-zumo-application` header to the request.

Comment: @JoyWang The `x-zumo-application` header is the old server API key. That's no longer used in the Mobile App services.

Comment: For your Postman request, also add a ZUMO-API-VERSION header with the value "2.0.0" (without quotes). For your Xamarin Forms app, did you update from the WindowsAzure.MobileServices library to  Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client to match?

Comment: Have you referenced https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter4/custom/#configuring-custom-apis? If any code demo could reproduce this issue will be helpful.

Comment: @EricHedstrom Let me try that additional header. Yes, I did update the nuget packages to the new mobile client packages.

Comment: @TomSun That reference is great, but it's for an API that uses the new mobile server nuget packages. My current API is still using the older nuget packages for Mobile Services. To allow for backwards compatibility, I would like to not make any nuget package changes to my API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still using the old nuget packages on the server, you still need the x-zumo-application HTTP header as well as the old client nuget packages. You have to update to the new nugets on the client side and server side at the same time. This is why you are seeing the Authorization failures you mentioned.

You may want to keep one service running with the old nuget packages for your existing client base, and have your new service running with the new nuget packages as your clients update. Once your client base has updated, shut down the old service.